# Reading environment variables in karate-config.js from kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, karate

I am currently working on creating a Jenkins job with Kubernetes and Karate to display a few test results using Cucumber reports. I am having difficulties trying to obtain environment variables passed into the deployment file through a configmap, as follows:

Deployment:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins-deployment
spec:
  
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
  replicas: 2 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: jenkins
          image: url/customjenkinsimage:tag
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: jenkins-configmap
```

ConfigMap:

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap 
apiVersion: v1 
metadata:
  name: jenkins-configmap 
data:
  # pass data as environment variables 
    URL_TO_TEST: "http://www.examplewebsite.com"
```

I looked this up and saw that some people mentioned using karate.properties['VAR_NAME'] inside the karate-config.js file and passing that through the config, but this resulted in my jenkins output telling me that the 'url' part in `Given url host1` doesn't exist. I've tried process.env as well (which of course doesn't work but it was worth a shot)

I was wondering if there is any way to access this environment variable in the karate-config.js (or even if I pass a json object in the configmap) since I would need it to build a url to pass to the feature for testing.

my karate-config.js:

```js
function fn() {  

    var config = {
        host1: karate.properties['URL_TO_TEST']
    };

    return config;
  }
```

All of these files get put into the /var/jenkins_home/jobs/karate_job/workspace/ folder to run using a Shell command: `cd /var/jenkins_home/jobs/karate_job/workspace/ ; java -jar karate.jar test.feature`.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I think `java.lang.System.getenv('PATH')` answers your question, let me know if not

Comment: Thank you, this works. I used https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_getenv_string.htm for further clarification, for my use case I had to replace PATH with my environment variable name. I fixed the env variable name in my post.